# How many answers are there on English Language & Usage?

Tags: discussion

At the time of writing there are 74,223 questions on EL&U. How many answers are there?

Comment: Do you need that number for personal statistics?

Answer (score 8):

The Data Explorer will provide reasonably up-to-date exact numbers (exact up to the last refresh), but even the front page of http://data.stackexchange.com/ shows an approximate figure:

[image: Screenshot of Data Explorer]

> - 74k questions
> - 184k answers
> - 556k comments
> - 976 tags

An existing [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/441236/number-of-answers) provides the following statistics as at the time of this edit:

Answers: 184317
Questions: 74068

The difference in the number of questions is because the Explorer data isn't quite up-to-date.

Comment: I think it updates every week or so.

Answer (score 7):

You can get an accurate and completely up-to-date count by using an [advanced search](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/searching) (you just need to be logged in, otherwise it only returns 500 results maximum).

When I search with `is:a` I get 254,853. When I first posted this answer, I got only 184,750.

[Try a search.](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa)